# Shift rows based on parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a new report for labels. To be able to use the whole paper with the labels i need to shift the rows down based on a parameter. Is this possible?

The first picture is how the label looks in the editor. Second picture is how the report looks when i run it. Last picture is how i want it.

```
Sql Query: SELECT
  Parts.PartName
  ,Orders.OrderId
  ,OrderCustomFields.[PD Number]
  ,OrderedParts.PartId
FROM
  Orders
  INNER JOIN OrderCustomFields
    ON Orders.OrderId = OrderCustomFields.Id
  INNER JOIN OrderedParts
    ON Orders.OrderId = OrderedParts.OrderId
  INNER JOIN Parts
    ON OrderedParts.PartId = Parts.Id
WHERE
  OrderCustomFields.[PD Number] = @PDNumber
```

[Editor]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pogsb.png)

[Result]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LR9b.png)

[Desired report layout]
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GfO0.png)

I tried to make it work with your awnser Alan. I do get a syntax error. 
What am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order BY Parts.PartName) as rn, Parts.PartName, Orders.OrderId, OrderCustomFields.[PD Number], OrderedParts.PartId
    FROM
      Orders
      INNER JOIN OrderCustomFields
        ON Orders.OrderId = OrderCustomFields.Id
      INNER JOIN OrderedParts
        ON Orders.OrderId = OrderedParts.OrderId
      INNER JOIN Parts
        ON OrderedParts.PartId = Parts.Id
    WHERE
      OrderCustomFields.[PD Number] = @PDNumber
    UNION All

    SELECT * FROM 
        ( -- get a sequence of numbers, make the rownumber negative
        select
            ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a.name) *-1 as rn
            , NULL as Parts.PartName
            , NULL as Orders.OrderId
            , NULL as OrderCustomFields.[PD Number]
            , NULL as OrderedParts.PartId
        From sys.all_objects a
    )topX
        WHERE rn >= @skip *-1 -- filter to only row number that are positive (real records) or lower than the skip value
        ORDER BY rn
```

Comment: I did upload the wrong picture to editor and result they should be swapped.

Comment: I've rearranged the images

Comment: You don't need the schema qualifiers on the column name aliases. So, instead of `, NULL as Parts.PartName` just use `, NULL as PartName` for example. In fact it does not matter what alias you use as long as they are the same type and order as the main part of the query. You may have to CAST the NULLs for example if OrderID is an int then you might have to do `, CAST(NULL AS int) AS PartName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have a sample of your data, this was done using the WideWorldImporters sample database but should be simple enough to follow.

I basically just appends x number of blanks rows at the start of the dataset based on a parameter `@skip`

declare @skip int = 3

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CustomerName, CityName) as rn
    , CustomerName
    , CityName
    from Website.Customers c
    WHERE BuyingGroupName ='Tailspin Toys'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 
    ( -- get a sequence of numbers, make the rownumber negative
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a.name) *-1 as rn
        , NULL as CustomerName
        , NULL as CityName
        from sys.all_objects a
    ) topX
    WHERE rn >= @skip *-1 -- filter to only row number that are positive (real records) or lower than the skip value
    ORDER BY rn
```

If you have a numbers table or similar you could use that instead of sys.all_objects, but this was just for illustration.

Comment: I solved it thanks!!!! i had some problems with my skip parameter, i replaced it and now it works i have no idea what coused that problem. I have to low rep to upvote but i tried.